# add a class to an element in a .map function with useState react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
<div>          
    {arrayCard.map((item, index) => {
            return (<Card key={index}  
                          onClick={(e) => handleClick(index, e)}  
                          src={item}   />) 
    })}
</div>
```

This is my Card component.

```
 <button  onClick={props.onClick}  className="focus:outline-none">
     <Image
           
           src={props.src}
           alt="Card Pic"
           width={80}
           height={80}
     />
   </button>
```

This is what I have inside my component. What I want to do is add a class to the clicked Card element. Each one has a different index but I don't know what to do with it.

I have a function handleClick and a useState() to do it.

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your `Card` Component:

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

const handleClick = (e) => {
  setIsActive(value => !value);
  props.onClick(e);
}

return (
  <button onClick={handleClick} className={`focus:outline-none ${isActive ? 'activeClass' : null}`}>
    <Image src={props.src} alt="Card Pic" width={80} height={80} />
  </button>
);
```

Comment: How could I disable the cards until I click another one and If they are the same disable both but if they are different enable them again?. I can disable them with the class onclick but how can I enable them when they are not equal? because that state is in the father component.